# Render template with context after creating objects

Tags: django

Consider a textarea input to enter emails. 
The view has a forloop: for each email the view tries to create a user. Then, if the user is created, I append it to my array "newUers", if the user already exists, I append it to the "alreadyUsers" array.

When the loop ends, I want to render a view with these arrays. But it does not work...
The users are correctly created but the view does not render the template.

Any idea?

**invitations.html**: a textarea with an an ajax call on submit

```
<div id="invitations">
    <label>Enter your clients email</label>
    <textarea v-model="invitations" class="textarea" id="invitations" name="invitations"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="Save" @click="submit()">
</div>
```

**user_invitation.js**: the ajax call (based on Vue)

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#invitations',
    data: {
        invitations: '',
    },
    methods: {
        submit: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/accounts/invitations/create/',
                data: {
                    invitations: this.invitations,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                context: this,
                success: function () {
                    console.log("ajax success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("ajax error");
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

**views.py**

```
def InvitationCreateView(request):
        newUsers = []
        alreadyUsers = []
        for client in request.POST['invitations'].split('\n'):
            try:
                # Get informations for creating the User
                user = User.objects.create(
                    username=client,
                    email=client,
                )
                user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='Clients'))
                user.save()
                newUsers.append(client)

            # Check if user already exists
            except IntegrityError:
                alreadyUsers.append(client)

        return render(request, 'accounts/agent_invitations_confirmation.html',
                      {"newUsers": newUsers, "alreadyUsers": alreadyUsers})
```

Comment: Because your Ajax success function does nothing other than log.

Comment: Do you feel strongly about staying on that page when you render the template? If you don't, you could just make a different view and use redirect.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Yes: don't use ajax.